# Custom folder field for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I would like to be able to add a custom field to folders in Windows 7, and then be able to show that column(field) when viewing the folder in Explorer (sort and group etc).

**Question:**

How can I achieve this? (is there a program I can buy / use or is there a way of doing this in Windows 7?)

Example use case: I have folders for each job that I do - I'd like to mark the folder as "pending", "done" etc. I'm using custom folder markers at the moment - but that's limited. Having a number of these fields would be really powerful.

Comment: Essentially your looking for a custom way to sort folders?

Comment: Not really ...  Windows has some amazing sorting and group features .. i want to add my own properties. I think I found a solution to this over at stack overflow. Will know soon.

Comment: I found this, probably what you are referring to on Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942112/custom-folder-field-for-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Explorer++](http://www.explorerplusplus.com/), which is an Explorer (the Windows shell) replacement. Explorer++ allows you to customise the interface.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to add fields.

Answer (score 0):

The Lamest way to mark a folder:

I have been using simple renaming of the folder itself. a **+** charachter put the folder highest in the sort (I am working on it)

```
+whereswaldo
Andrew
chimo
derrek
```

a **-** charachter does not change the sort (done with it)

```
Andrew
chimo
-derrek
whereswaldo
```

and of course Numbers added to the front would change the sort again.

```
02derrek
03Fraley
Andrew
chimo
whereswaldo
```

It is Not the answer , but it has been easy , simple and no program has to understand comprehend or insure that it copies with the files/folders.  It has one caveat, sometimes a program has the folder opened to it (will not rename), I have to close that program to complete the renaming of the folder.  There are other odd charachters you can find on your keyboard that will change the sort , just tag, or even hide , and are "valid" charachters for a folder. I find that this simplest method has also (usually) still worked well in other OSes, like the portable devices.